# Unit-testing in Racket with multiple outputs

Tags: unit-testing, lisp, racket

I am trying to use unit-tests with Racket.

Usually, I am successful and I really like rackunit. However, I am having trouble with this specific case.

The function to be tested outputs two values. How can I test this using rackunit?

When I call:

```
(game-iter 10)
>>  5 10
```

I tried using this test:

```
(check-equal? (game-iter 10) 5 10)
```

However, it fails:

```
. . result arity mismatch;
 expected number of values not received
  expected: 1
  received: 2
  values...:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that already exists, so I came up with the long way to do it. If you don't have many functions that return multiple values, you could do something like

```
(define-values (a b) (game-iter 10))
(check-equal? a 5)
(check-equal? b 10)
```

You can pick better names for `a` and `b`.

You can abstract this somewhat with something like:

```
;; check if (game-iter n) produces (values a-expect b-expect)
(define-simple-check (check-game-iter n a-expect b-expect)
  (define-values (a b) (game-iter n))
  (and (equal? a a-expect)
       (equal? b b-expect)))
(check-game-iter 10 5 10)
```

(Again, pick better names than `a` `b`.)

If you want to make this even more general, take a look at [`call-with-values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html?q=call-with-values#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-values%29%29).

Answer (score 2):

#### A simple macro approach

@Gibstick's answer is right on, but I wanted to illustrate a more general approach that somebody on the #racket irc channel gave to me many months ago:

```rkt
(define-syntax check-values-equal?
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ a b) (check-equal? (call-with-values (thunk a) list)
                           b)]))
```

You'd use it like this:

```
(check-values-equal? (game-iter 10) '(5 10))
```

There is some room for improvement (such as adding support for the third argument of the `check-equal?` macro, however, I find this works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

@Winny 's answer is not working for me. However I find this useful:

```rkt
(define-syntax check-values-equal?
    (syntax-rules ()
      [(_ a b) (check-equal? (call-with-values (lambda () a) list)
                             (call-with-values (lambda () b) list))])))
```